# JavaFX bug, cannot set any event to TableColumn

Tags: javafx

```
tableView.getColumns().forEach(column -> {
        column.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, event -> {
            System.out.println("Mouse entered on column: " + column.getText());
        });
    });
```

That should work, right? Tested in version 20, 21 and 22. For some reason it does not work.

Comment: @Slaw, it's true tableColumns aren't nodes itself, but I wonder why these have addEventFilter() and addEventHandler() methods

Comment: So, it's not a bug, it is just an unsupported feature.  The event you are trying to handle (a mouse event) is not generated for the target (the column) on which you are trying to handle the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `TableColumn` is not a `Node` and so is not actually part of the scene graph. It is not designed to receive input events. Also, neither `TableView` nor its default skin explicitly include columns in the event dispatch chain, meaning no column will receive **any** event fired at its associated cells.

`TableColumn` has methods like `addEventHandler` because it implements [`EventTarget`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/22/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventTarget.html). It implements this interface so it can be the target of a [`CellEditEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/22/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellEditEvent.html). That is why the API also includes specific properties such as `onEditStart`.

If you need to listen for mouse events on a "column" then you should add event handlers to the *cells* via the cell factory.

```java
column.setCellFactory(
    tc -> {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      var cell = (TableCell<S, T>) TableColumn.DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY.call(tc);
      cell.setOnMouseEntered(System.out::println);
      return cell;
    });
```

Here you will have a direct reference to the column in the mouse-entered handler, or you could get the column from the cell. You can of course replace the use of the default cell factory with a custom cell implementation if needed. That said, note the above will not add an event handler to the column's *header*.